# SBCL "subst" efficiency

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I just wrote a program that calls `subst` inside a loop, along with a number of other functions, and by far, the `subst` function calls take the most amount of time. Below is a notional snippet of code that contains the spirit of the program i wrote.

```
    (loop
       with bindings = ((symbol1 . 1) (sybmol2 . 2) ... (sybmoln . n))
       with x-copy
       for x in xs
       do
         ...
         (setq x-copy (copy-cpd x))
         (setf (cpd-identifiers1 x-copy) (subst-bindings bindings (cpd-identifiers1 x)))
         (setf (cpd-identifiers2 x-copy) (subst-bindings bindings (cpd-identifiers2 x)))
         ...)
```

`subst-bindings` makes recursive calls to `subst` internally:

```
(defun subst-bindings (bindings generic)
  (cond ((null bindings) generic)
    (t (subst-bindings (cdr bindings)
               (subst (cdar bindings) (caar bindings) generic)))))
```

I ran my actual code with the statistical profiler enabled, and I got these results:

```
           Self        Total        Cumul
  Nr  Count     %  Count     %  Count     %    Calls  Function
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   4585  45.8   6840  68.4   4585  45.8        -  (LABELS SB-IMPL::S :IN SUBST)
   2   2204  22.0   2205  22.1   6789  67.9        -  EQL
   3    489   4.9    489   4.9   7278  72.8        -  SUBST
   4    315   3.2   7537  75.4   7593  75.9        -  SUBST-BINDINGS
   5    150   1.5    235   2.3   7743  77.4        -  PPRINT-DISPATCH
   6    143   1.4    274   2.7   7886  78.9        -  SB-IMPL::%FIND-SYMBOL
   7    114   1.1    114   1.1   8000  80.0        -  SB-IMPL::%MAKE-STRING-OUTPUT-STREAM
   8    106   1.1    347   3.5   8106  81.1        -  SB-KERNEL:OUTPUT-SYMBOL-NAME
   9     94   0.9    113   1.1   8200  82.0        -  SB-IMPL::STRING-SOUT
  10     73   0.7    155   1.5   8273  82.7        -  SB-KERNEL::VALUES-SPECIFIER-TYPE-R
  11     70   0.7     70   0.7   8343  83.4        -  SB-KERNEL:UB32-BASH-COPY
  12     56   0.6     56   0.6   8399  84.0        -  SB-KERNEL:%SXHASH-SIMPLE-SUBSTRING
  13     51   0.5     51   0.5   8450  84.5        -  MAKE-CPD
  14     48   0.5    160   1.6   8498  85.0        -  GET-OUTPUT-STREAM-STRING
  15     48   0.5     48   0.5   8546  85.5        -  WRITE-STRING
  16     44   0.4     44   0.4   8590  85.9        -  SB-KERNEL:%COERCE-CALLABLE-TO-FUN
  17     43   0.4    741   7.4   8633  86.3        -  PRINC
  18     43   0.4     60   0.6   8676  86.8        -  POSITION
  19     39   0.4    151   1.5   8715  87.2        -  SB-IMPL::%WRITE-STRING
  20     39   0.4     46   0.5   8754  87.5        -  SB-KERNEL:STRING=*
  21     37   0.4    195   2.0   8791  87.9        -  SB-KERNEL::SPECIFIER-TYPE-R
  22     37   0.4    169   1.7   8828  88.3        -  OPERATE-FACTOR
  23     36   0.4     68   0.7   8864  88.6        -  SB-VM::GENERIC-+
  24     36   0.4     36   0.4   8900  89.0        -  COPY-LIST
  25     35   0.4    231   2.3   8935  89.4        -  SB-KERNEL:SPECIFIER-TYPE
  26     33   0.3    314   3.1   8968  89.7        -  SB-INT:%INTERN
  27     32   0.3   9146  91.5   9000  90.0        -  CANDIDATE-NODES
  28     31   0.3     31   0.3   9031  90.3        -  SB-IMPL::SETUP-PRINTER-STATE
  29     30   0.3     79   0.8   9061  90.6        -  COPY-SEQ
  30     30   0.3     45   0.4   9091  90.9        -  GET-FULLY-QUALIFIED-CPD-VARS
  31     30   0.3     30   0.3   9121  91.2        -  SB-IMPL::OUTPUT-SYMBOL
  32     28   0.3   1724  17.2   9149  91.5        -  GENERATE-CPD-VARS
  33     26   0.3     63   0.6   9175  91.8        -  SB-INT:EQUAL-BUT-NO-CAR-RECURSION
  34     25   0.3     25   0.3   9200  92.0        -  SB-IMPL::VECTOR-SUBSEQ-DISPATCH/SIMPLE-VECTOR
  35     24   0.2     24   0.2   9224  92.2        -  (SB-IMPL::OPTIMIZED-DATA-VECTOR-REF T)
  36     23   0.2     23   0.2   9247  92.5        -  SB-KERNEL:HAIRY-DATA-VECTOR-REF/CHECK-BOUNDS
  37     21   0.2    685   6.8   9268  92.7        -  (LABELS SB-IMPL::HANDLE-IT :IN SB-KERNEL:OUTPUT-OBJECT)
  38     20   0.2     70   0.7   9288  92.9        -  SB-IMPL::COMPUTE-SYMBOL-HASH
  39     19   0.2   1295  12.9   9307  93.1        -  COMBINE-SYMBOLS
  40     19   0.2    395   4.0   9326  93.3        -  INTERN
  41     19   0.2    104   1.0   9345  93.5        -  (FLET SB-IMPL::REPLACE-ALL :IN GET-OUTPUT-STREAM-STRING)
  42     19   0.2     19   0.2   9364  93.6        -  SB-C:RETURN-MULTIPLE
  43     19   0.2     19   0.2   9383  93.8        -  SB-KERNEL:VECTOR-SUBSEQ*
  44     18   0.2    133   1.3   9401  94.0        -  COPY-CPD
```

The SBCL User manual describes how to interpret this table:

> For each function, the table will show three absolute and relative
>   sample counts. The Self column shows samples taken while directly
>   executing that function. The Total column shows samples taken while
>   executing that function or functions called from it (sampled to a
>   platform-specific depth). The Cumul column shows the sum of all Self
>   columns up to and including that line in the table.

As you can see, two of the first three entries are subst-related functions and the percentage of samples taken during these functions is disproportionately more than the rest of the function calls. This makes me wonder, is `subst` is implemented in an efficient way in sbcl? If not, are there any more efficient alternatives I could use to perform substitutions?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `SUBST` is O(n), where `n` is the number of nodes (both conses and leaves) in the tree being searched.

Comment: A better approach might be to put the bindings into a hash table. Then write your own recursive function that walks the tree, checks whether the current node is in the hash table, and replaces it with the binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the standard functions `sublis` and `nsublis`. They use an assoc list for the substitutions.

```
CL-USER > (sublis '((x . 10) (y . 20))
                  '(* x (+ x y) (* y y)))
(* 10 (+ 10 20) (* 20 20))
```

Style:

I would not write the substitution function in a recursive style.

```
(defun subst-bindings (bindings generic)
  (loop for (b v) in bindings
        do (setf generic (subst v b generic)))
  generic)
```

Above ensures that it is actually a loop and the destructuring makes the code a bit shorter to read in this case. In portable Common Lisp tail recursive functions are not always converted to an efficient loop.